# Rust: problem using ndarray-linalg & ndarray crates

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, rust-crates

I am writing a cross compiled library in Rust (that will work on IOS/Android/Linux/MacOS). I am using [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.1/ndarray/) to implement the algorithms.

I need to calculate the norm of an ArrayBase. I found [ndarray-linalg](https://docs.rs/ndarray-linalg/0.13.1/ndarray_linalg/index.html) which is a crate that implements lots of traits on ndarray's types.

But I am unable to use it:

```
// Cargo.toml
ndarray = { version = "0.15.1", default-features = true } 
ndarray-linalg = {version = "0.13.1"}

// src/main.rs
use ndarray::*;
use ndarray_linalg::*;

fn main() {
    let foo = ArrayBase::from(&[1,2,3]);
    foo.norm_l2(); // produces error
      //^^^^^^^ method not found in `&ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
}
```

So here I have 2 questions:

1. How to solve this problem and make these methods accessible in my program ?
2. Is it a good idea to use these crates for compiling against android & IOS architectures anyway?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ndarray-linalg` version 0.13.1 requires `ndarray` version 0.14. So you could either reduce your `ndarray` version to 0.14, in which case your code will work, or remove the `ndarray-linalg` dependency. If you want to stay on `ndarray` 0.15.1 and only need to compute an L2 norm, it may be easiest to implement that yourself in a couple of lines.

`ndarray` version 0.15 was only released a week ago, so there might be an `ndarray-linalg` release that supports it soon.

`ndarray-linalg` currently only supports the `x86_64` instruction set.